# Dynamically Theme Angular2 with value from database

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-services

I have a question in regards to the angular2+ theming. I am trying to set values in Firestore to then be fetched by and angular2+ application as it is loading and dynamically set the primary and secondary colors.

In AngularJS there was a service labeled $mdThemingProvider (link: https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.4/api/service/$mdThemingProvider) which allowed setting of themes in script code.

I have not seen anything like this in Angular2 or AngularMaterial.io. Any and all help is very appreciated. I would really like to find a solution for the theming here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From [AngularMaterial.io](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#multiple-themes):

> Multiple themes
>
> You can create multiple themes for your application by including the
>   angular-material-theme mixin multiple times, where each inclusion is
>   gated by an additional CSS class.

The example they provide shows how to define two themes (`$candy-app-theme` and `$dark-theme`) and uses a class to apply the dark theme to any component inside. In our case, I imagine we would fetch the theme value from Firebase and bind to a class.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but in this case the options for colors could be a combination of any two material colors so I cannot create themes based around every possible combination. I have a specific case where I need to generate the theme after a service fetches colors from firebase. I appreciate the help here! Thanks!

Comment: Ah, are you trying to let the user pick a primary and accent color? Have a look at the Material.io color tool to see how they're implementing dynamic colors. I'll see if I can find a link and update my post later.

Comment: Yes the desired functionality would let the user pick colors. Unfortunately the Material.io color tool is using angularjs not Angular2+. Thanks for the link, I appreciate the help here!